# ERROR: In <declare-styleable> NavArgument, unable to find attribute type

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to integrate [these libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) into my Android project to make a navigation controller. 
When I add in these two lines to my build.gradle -

`implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha01'
 implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha01'`

It syncs ok, but in build I get this error:

ERROR: In  NavArgument, unable to find attribute type.

I was able to build [Google's sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) that uses the relevant libraries without problems.

My project has:

- androidSupportLibrary 27.1.1
- projectTargetVersion 27
- projectCompileSdkVersion android-P
- projectBuildToolsVersion 27.0.2
- gradleVersion 3.0.1
- gradlePlugin 4.4

I've already tried upgrading all these versions^, doing a clean build, restarting Android Studio, etc.

I also get some Java compiler errors.

Any thoughts on why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the navigation value in your project :

[add navigation xml](https://d33ypg4xwx0n86.cloudfront.net/direct?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-images-1.medium.com%2Fmax%2F1600%2F1*CnKW5icuwF8_13SGBdEOUA.png&resize=w1408)

and after that, if you have an error

`invalid resource directory name: ..../res/merged/debug  navigation`

you need to remove `android.enableAapt2=false` from your gradle.properties